# angular2 datatable - override Default Sorter and pagination?

Tags: angular, datatable, pagination, angular2-directives

I am using [angular2-datatable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-datatable) in my projects to show some tables of data.

For now, I load 100 items and the sorting & pagination are done on the loaded items.

In my case, my users have around 3K objects each, so I don't want to load them all into my table.

However I want to be able to do some pagination and some sorting myself, using my API.

-> But for that, I need to be able to override the `mfDefaultSorter`

I have this  :

```
<table class="table  table-hover table-outline mb-0 " [mfData]="items" #mf="mfDataTable" [mfRowsOnPage]="RowsOnPage" >
  <thead class="thead-default">
     <tr>

       <th>
         <mfDefaultSorter by="type">Type</mfDefaultSorter>
       </th>

    </tr>
 .....
```

so here, the `mfDefaultSorter` will sort the items by my field 'type'.
But now I want it to go in a method of my `component.component.ts` so I can do the sorting with my API

and with the same ideas, the pagination is done on the loaded items,
But I want to be able to do it from my API.

**Any ideas ?**

if the package is not able to do that, do you have another package in mind ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can change the parameter by `[by]="yourmethodname"`
And do the required sorting in that method.
Refer this [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-datatable-pagination)